# Assigning NAs to values in a list

Tags: r

I have a data frame that includes many variables. Here is a shortened version of what I have so far:

```
n_20010_0_0 <- c(1,2,3,4)
n_20010_0_1 <- c(0, -2, NA, 4)  
n_20010_0_2 <- c(3, 0, -7, 2)

x <- data.frame (n_20010_0_0, n_20010_0_1, n_20010_0_2)
```

I created a new variable that returns whether or not there is a 1 within the list of variables:

```
 MotherIllness0 <- paste("n_20010_0_", 0:2, sep = "")
 x$MotherCAD_0_0 <- apply(x, 1, function(x) as.integer(any(x[MotherIllness0] == 1, na.rm = TRUE)))
```

I would like to keep the NAs as 0's, but I  would also  like to recode it so that if there is a -7 the new value is NA. 
This is what I've tried and it doesn't work:

```
x$MotherCAD_0_0[MotherIllness0 == -7] <- NA
```

Comment: Do you mean "If a column in x contains a -7, its result in MotherCAD_0_0 should be NA?"

Comment: Your question is not hard at all. Only if you can express yourself clearly.

Comment: You could do `x$MotherCAD_0_0[rowSums(x[,MotherIllness0]==-7,na.rm=T)>=1]=NA`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you don't need to define `MotherIllness0`, the argument 1 in your `apply` function takes care of that.

Here's a line of code that does both things you want.

```
MotherIllness0 <- paste("n_20010_0_", 0:2, sep = "")    
x$MotherCAD_0_0<- apply(x[,MotherIllness0], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x==-7), NA,    
                                                     as.integer(any(x==1, na.rm=T))))
```

I assumed that a row with both 1s and -7s should have NA for the new variable. If not, then this should work:

```
x$MotherCAD_0_0<- apply(x[,MotherIllness0], 1, function(x) ifelse(any(x==1, na.rm=T), 1,
                                                 ifelse(any(x==-7), NA, 0)))
```

Note that with the example you have above, these two lines should produce the same outcome.

Comment: `apply(MARGIN = 1)` is actually working on each row at a time, and `MotherIllness0` is selecting columns from each row. Presumably there are more columns than shown here, but the OP only wants to perform this operation on a subset of them.

Comment: @MattParker touche! It just wasn't clear from the example. I'm editing the code accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, without using any if-else logic:

```
# Here's your dataset, with a row including both 1 and -7 added:
x <- data.frame (n_20010_0_0 = c(1, 2, 3, 4, 1),
                 n_20010_0_1 = c(0, -2, NA, 4, 0) , 
                 n_20010_0_2 = c(3, 0, -7, 2, -7)
)

# Your original function:
MotherIllness0 <- paste("n_20010_0_", 0:2, sep = "")

x$MotherCAD_0_0 <- apply(x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(x) {
    as.integer(
        any(x[MotherIllness0] == 1, na.rm = TRUE)
    )
})

# A simplified version
x$test <- apply(x, MARGIN = 1, FUN = function(row) {

    as.integer(
        any(row[MotherIllness0] == 1, na.rm = TRUE) & 
        !any(row[MotherIllness0] == -7, na.rm = TRUE)
    )

})
```

A couple of notes: the name of `x` in an anonymous function like `function(x)` can be anything, and you'll save yourself a lot of confusion by calling it what it is (I named it `row` above).

It's also unlikely that you actually need to convert your result column to integer - logical columns are easier to interpret, and they work the same as 0-1 columns for just about everything (e.g., `TRUE + FALSE` equals 1).